# Ajuda com URL Amigável com PHP e htacess

Tags: php, htaccess, url-amigavel

Sou novo na programação em PHP, criei um site dinâmico usando o seguinte código:

```
   <nav>
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="?pag=home">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="?pag=contato">Contato</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

    <?php
    $paginas = @$_GET['pag'];
    switch ($paginas) {
        default :
            include 'home.php';
            break;

        case 'home':
            include 'home.php';
            break;

        case 'contato':
            include 'contato.php';
            break;
    }
    ?>

    <footer>

    </footer>
```

A Barra de navegação e o rodapé são fixos, tendo o "switche" do PHP trocando o conteúdo central.

Para requisitar a troca do conteúdo uso o seguinte link:

```
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="?pag=contato">Contato</a>
        </li>
```

Minha URL fica assim: http://www.meusite.com.br/?pag=cotato. Mas eu gostaria que ela ficasse assim: http://www.meusite.com.br/contato.

Porém, já tentei de tudo o que eu sei sobre PHP pra achar uma solução, mas não consigo resolver, me ajudem por favor.

Comment: Bem vindo Marcos, edite sua pergunta e coloque o código, não a imagem, facilita o pessoal te ajudar

Comment: Obrigado pela dica Pedro, já fiz a mudança

Answer (score 1):

Você pode pegar a URI 
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

E trabalhar nela para lhe atender.

Faz um explode por / verifica qual será o indice em que termina o dominio e os próximos vc sabe que vai ser o controller e para onde vai direcionar.

Comment: $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] 
Já faz a captura depois da / só fazer o explode e obter as informacoes caso vc tenha

/fale-conosco/telefone
/fale-conosco/email

e queira tratar serarado

Comment: Olá Felipe, sou muito iniciante em PHP, sei muito pouco mesmo, comecei agora a estudar PHP. Muito do que você explicou não entendi nada! rsrsrs Me desculpe.

Comment: :) 
Que isso estamos aqui para ajudar.

  <?php
        $arrUri = explode("/", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
        switch ($arrUri[1]) {
            case 'home':
                include 'home.php';
                break;
            case 'contato':
                include 'contato.php';
                break;
            default :
                include 'home.php';
            break;
        }
    ?>

e tenta acessar com a url amigavel ("http://www.meusite.com.br/contato.")

Answer (score 0):

Estou adicionando uma nova resposta com o código a ser testado

```html
<?php
        $arrUri = explode("/", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
        switch ($arrUri[1]) {
            case 'home':
                include 'home.php';
                break;
            case 'contato':
                include 'contato.php';
                break;
            default :
                include 'home.php';
            break;
        }
?>
```

e tenta acessar com a url amigavel ("meusite.com.br/contato.")

Comment: Olá Felipe! Obrigado, mas não funcionou.

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver!

No meu arquivo `.htaccess` eu escrevi o seguinte:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?pag=$1

Daí criei um pequeno PHP pra receber o valor da variável 'pag':

$getUrl = strip_tags(trim(filter_input(INPUT_GET,'pag',FILTER_DEFAULT))); // Filtra o que é digitado na url
$setUrl = (empty($getUrl) ? 'home' : $getUrl);  //Define o valor padrão para a variável
$Url = explode('/', $setUrl); // Cria um array com o que vai sendo inserido na URL
```

Answer (score -2):

Assumindo que você está utilizando o Apache2 com o **mod_rewrite ativado** no seu servidor PHP, você deve criar um arquivo **.htaccess** na raiz do seu site com o seguinte código:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/(.*)/$ /?pag=$1
```

Quando o usuário tentar acessar por exemplo http://meusite.com.br/faleconosco/, o Apache vai pegar qualquer coisa que for colocada entre as duas barras /(.*)/, no caso 'faleconosco', e reescrever para o formato atual: http://meusite.com.br/?pag=faleconosco

Como você deve ter vários outros arquivos no seu site, o código acima pode deixar outras URLs confusas, caso do header e do footer do seu site que você mencionou nos comentários. Para evitar isso, você pode redirecionar cada uma das páginas especificamente no seu .htaccess do seguinte modo:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/home/?$ /?pag=home
RewriteRule ^/contato/?$ /?pag=contato
RewriteRule ^/faleconosco/?$ /?pag=faleconosco
```

Comment: Estou começando a mexer com PHP faz muito pouco tempo.

Funcionou em parte. Esqueci de mencionar que antes do PHP e logo depois tem um HEADER e um FOOTER fixos e esse código PHP somente substitui o conteúdo central

Comment: Então Antoni, editei minha pergunta, acredito que agora dê pra intender melhor

Comment: O que funcionou? O que não deu certo? Marcos, o seu código está correto. Na verdade, os links do menu que você fez, também podem ficar no formato desejado, ou seja: somente /home e /contato. Para ter as URLs amigáveis, você precisa criar o .htaccess e ensinar o apache a interpretar as URLs do seu site. Na minha resposta, expliquei exatamente como ficaria para o seu caso: pegar tudo após o site e enviar ao index.php como o complemento da variável pag.

Comment: A URL funcionou, mas o HEADER e o FOOTER sumiram, era para eles ficarem fixos e só mudar o corpo da página.

Comment: se quiser visualizar um site que estou fazendo: http://www.adrnet.com.br

Comment: Marcos, não funcionou porque o HEADER e o FOOTER tb são arquivos no seu site. O código que eu fiz, faz com que qualquer URL seja reescrita para este formato que você solicitou. Você pode criar regras somente para as páginas que você fizer. Exemplo: RewriteRule ^/contato$ /?pag=contato